# sass and bootstrap issue with importing scss file

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

M using sass with bootstrap 4 n now what i do here is sass folder i have app.scss file wherein i have

```
@import _customVariables.scss
@import node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions
@import node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins
```

when i compile the sass file i get the following error

```
sass --watch app.scss:style.css
 Error: Expected string.
 @import _customVariables.scss
         ^
 app.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

as m newbie to sass y is it not importing the files

it works for the following only when i have the entire bootstrap it comiples

```
  @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `scss` you should use string for the import value and omit the underscore:

```
@import 'customVariables.scss';
```

As per SASS documentation (https://sass-lang.com/guide#import):

> Let's say you have a couple of Sass files, _reset.scss, and base.scss. We want to import _reset.scss into base.scss.
>
> `@import 'reset';`

---

**EDIT**: Provide a working example so the OP is able to see all dependent parts working together.

I've created a project on codesandbox, where I've added `sass` and `bootstrap` and used the guide on bootstrap to theme the build:

https://codesandbox.io/s/v0k9wlwqx3

Comment: this is yet not working out . it works only when i have the entire bootstrap @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" but  not  any cutom file

Comment: It's hard to get any help without more info, what is the error you have now?

Comment: Added an example so you can see a full example working and only importing the minimal set of components form bootstrap.