# sass bootstrap4 is not getting applied to my html file

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

m newbie to sass i have this html file to which i hve applied sass

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="sass/app.scss" rel="stylesheet" >
 </head>
<body>
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhllllllllllllll
</body>
</html>
```

and my app.scss

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

 body {
 font: 100% $font-size-lg;
color: $red;
 }
```

these body scss is not getting applied to the html file any help would be appreciated

Comment: SASS is not parsed in the browser. You must compile the SASS to CSS first. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215517/attaching-a-sass-scss-to-html-docs

Comment: @Zim can u please lookout for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757719/sass-and-bootstrap-issue-with-importing-scss-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.scss

```
$primary: #3498db;
 $secondary: #e67e22;
$success: #2eeeff;
$danger: #e74c3c;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

 /*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

html

```
 <link href="scss/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```