# css is not being applied to buttons using sass and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am working onto a page using `sass` and Bootstrap 4 but then the `css` is not being applied.

My folder structure:

```
scss 
   styles.scss
   styles.css
   styles.css.map
node_modules 
   all sass n bootstrap files
layout.html
package-lock
```

In my `styles.scss` I have the following:

```
$primary: #3498db;
$secondary: #e67e22;
$success: #2eeeff;
$danger: #e74c3c;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

On my layouts I have:

```
<link href="scss/styles.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or

```
<link href="scss/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My button code:

```
<div class="col-md-auto col-4">
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mr-1">Primary</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-auto col-4">
   <button class="btn btn-lg .btn-success">Primary Outline</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-auto col-4">
   <button class="btn btn-lg .btn-danger">Primary Active</button>
</div>
```

But my `styles.scss` is not applied  to any of my buttons.

If I use:

```
<link href="scss/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then it applies only the Bootstrap, not the `.scss` stylings. Any help is appreciated, please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Did you try to override using the `$theme-colors` map ? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#modify-map

Comment: nope do v need to

Comment: have a look at this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

Comment: may be you needs to change `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` to `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

Comment: @Tested Check CSS file, is this file has correct code??

Comment: @Tested which scss to css modules you are using.
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275

Comment: @JunedLanja    $body-bg: #e2322e;
$body-color: #111;  works not the buttons

Comment: @AnkitGupta for buttons style is not appling

Comment: if you are not aware of scss to css coversion please go through below link.https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275

Comment: @AnkitGupta m newbie have started working onto it everthing works just that change in sass not appling onto buttons

Comment: You've already asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759124/sass-bootstrap4-is-not-getting-applied-to-my-html-file .. you can't link to SCSS files. They must be compiled to CSS.

Comment: @Tested https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275

Comment: @Tested use `$theme-colors` map

Comment: @Zim  there was an import issue  and this is a different question

Comment: @Arkellys n Juned  that works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks everyone for your great help
the following worked cheers :)

```
 $body-bg: #e2322e;
 $body-color: #111;
 $theme-colors: (
"primary": #ffffff,
"success": #000000
);
```